# Twilio response dateSent property null

Tags: php, json, object, twilio

**Use Context:** Processing the response object from a Twilio API request in PHP.

**Problem:** I get a valid response JSON from Twilio, but the property `date_sent:null`, and subsequently the PHP object renders as `[dateSent => ]`.

**Other, Similar Questions:** I found a similar question, but the solution won't work for me because in that question the poster IS getting a date_sent value; but the response I get is `date_sent:null`. Where the solution to that poster's question is simply a matter of formatting, in the present circumstances, I can't even do that: [Twilio PHP API how to get message timestamp DateSent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153691/twilio-php-api-how-to-get-message-timestamp-datesent)

Incidentally, in the meant time I'm using dateCreated, and it does work, but the assumption I don't want to live with is that dateCreated will always == dateSent.

Here's how I process it in PHP:

Sample PHP Code:

```
// Parse the Twilio response object for the date-time that the sms was sent.
$sms_sent = $response->dateSent->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // <--!!! **right here, throws error**
// Convert datetime to Unix timestamp
$timestamp = strtotime($sms_sent);
// Subtract time from datetime
$time = $timestamp - (5 * 60 * 60); // "5" is GMT -5 hours. 
// Date and time after subtraction
$datetimesent = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

In the object sample code you'll notice that dateSent doesn't have a value.

**Sample PHP Object:**

```
[properties:protected] => Array
    (
        [accountSid] => BD4512e9c6dcccc35edfb902a3e1b8621d
        [apiVersion] => 2010-04-01
        [body] => Jeff is in your office.
        [dateCreated] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2020-04-23 15:43:01.000000
                [timezone_type] => 1
                [timezone] => +00:00
            )

        [dateUpdated] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2020-04-23 15:43:01.000000
                [timezone_type] => 1
                [timezone] => +00:00
            )

        [dateSent] =>    // notice dateSent has no value.
        [direction] => outbound-api
        [errorCode] => 
        [errorMessage] => 
        [from] => +15555555555
```

Should I just give up and use dateCreated? As an aside, I think this code used to work for me, not sure when it started failing (or when I started not getting the dateSent value).

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  We used to get a dateSent value but are now getting `null`.  Did you ever figure out what happened?

Comment: @TracyB. , I'm looking up what I did for you bud. I'll post my solution in short order, and remove this message.